# Can't drop possibly corrupted table on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nextcloud

I’m running Nextcloud inside docker (one container for Nextcloud 21.0.2, one for MariaDB version `10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal`). Yesterday, after my server crashed, I was welcomed with an internal server error screen at my cloud’s landing page. Nextcloud’s log shows something like this every time I refresh:

```
"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\DriverException: An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'nextcloud.oc_authtoken' doesn't exist in engine"
```

It seems like the table nextcloud.oc_authtoken is not found, but at least SHOW TABLES shows it in the Mariadb container.

Following [this](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/mysql-and-supposedly-missing-oc-authtoken-table/49047/2) thread, I tried this without success:

```
MariaDB [nextcloud]> describe oc_authtoken;
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'nextcloud.oc_authtoken' doesn't exist in engine
MariaDB [nextcloud]> CREATE TABLE oc_authtoken (
    -> id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> uid VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> login_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    -> password LONGTEXT,
    -> name LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    -> token VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    -> type SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> last_activity INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> last_check INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> remember SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> scope LONGTEXT,
    -> expires INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    -> private_key LONGTEXT,
    -> public_key LONGTEXT,
    -> version SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    -> password_invalid TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')
    -> ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'oc_authtoken' already exists
```

Also, I’ve tried to drop the table first, but the process seem to hang: no feedback, and it seems to never end. So I have a table that is both missing and also exists. Maybe it's corrupted? Any recommendation?

Edit: docker logs tail for the database container:

```
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed page type (17855); stored checksum in field1 329391313; calculated checksums for field1: crc32 2787941462, innodb 2146028444, none 3735928559; page LSN 68614791028; page number (if stored to page already) 5; space id (if stored to page already) 19
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 70
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Index 70 is `authtoken_last_activity_idx` in table `nextcloud`.`oc_authtoken`
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB:  You can use CHECK TABLE to scan your table for corruption. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed read of file './nextcloud/oc_authtoken.ibd' page [page id: space=19, page number=5]. You may have to recover from a backup.
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (8192 bytes):
 len 8192; hex ******
InnoDB: End of page dump
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed page type (17855); stored checksum in field1 329391313; calculated checksums for field1: crc32 2787941462, innodb 2146028444, none 3735928559; page LSN 68614791028; page number (if stored to page already) 5; space id (if stored to page already) 19
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 70
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Index 70 is `authtoken_last_activity_idx` in table `nextcloud`.`oc_authtoken`
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Note] InnoDB:  You can use CHECK TABLE to scan your table for corruption. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2021-08-24 19:10:55 0 [Warning] InnoDB: btr_pcur_open_low level: 0 called from file: /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/mariadb-10.5.9/storage/innobase/row/row0row.cc line: 1301 table: `nextcloud`.`oc_authtoken` index: `authtoken_last_activity_idx` error: Page read from tablespace is corrupted.
error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type jsonlog.JSONLog
```

Comment: [MariaDB Server Documentation » ... » InnoDB Recovery Modes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/)

Comment: Include the container log of mariadb since startup. Which mariadb container version?

Comment: I've included now the docker logs tail (there's numerous similar messages) and the mariadb version.